# Extract list of values in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I have a pandas object that has a column called `'text'` for training input and a column called `'labels'` for training output.

```py
# 2d array with float32 values in the shape (300)
print(df['text'])
#=> 0    [[4.8312, 1.5674, -1.1444, -2.9088, -3.2264, 3...
#=> 0    [[2.5453, 2.2064, -0.913, 1.0133, -3.8835, 8.3...
#=> Name: text, dtype: object
```

```py
# 2d array with either 0 or 1 as values in the shape (1)
print(df['labels'])
#=> 0                  [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]
#=> 0    [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0....
#=> Name: labels, dtype: object
```

In order to pass them to `keras.fit()`, I'll need to convert each column to an nparray.

I want the nparray for `'text'` to look like:

```py
#=> [
#=>  [[4.8312, 1.5674, -1.1444, -2.9088, -3.2264, 3...
#=>  [[2.5453, 2.2064, -0.913, 1.0133, -3.8835, 8.3...
#=> ]
```

and the nparray for `'labels'` to look like:

```py
#=> [
#=>  [[0.], [0.], [0.], [0.], [0.], ...
#=>  [[0.], [0.], [0.], [0.], [0.], ...
#=> ]
```

Why didn't this work? Where did the additional `array()` object come from and how do I get the values in a way that works?

```py
print(a['labels'].values)
#=> [array([[0.],
#=>         [0.],
#=>         [0.],
#=>         [0.],
#=>         [0.]], dtype=float32) array([[0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.],
#=>                                      [0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Do you need `print(np.array(df['text'].tolist()))` and `print(np.array(df['labels'].tolist()))` ? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array()` indicates that the array in the first argument is actually a numpy array. It doesn't actually mean an additional array was created.